# How to write DateTime by using LinqToDB in Postgres DB field 'timestamp without time zone'?

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq2db

C# + Linq2db + Postgres

entity for table

```
[Table("my_table", Schema = "myScheme")]
public class TableEntity 
... [Column("dt", DbType = "timestamp without time zone", DataType = DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime DT { get; set; }...
```

I set value of the entity

```
tableEntity.DT = DateTime.SpecifyKind(someDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
//In debugger I see, that here Kind for tableEntity.DT is DateTimeKind.Local
```

next row start LinqToDb command:

```
dataConn.InsertWithInt32IdentityAsync(loanContractEntity);
```

but underhood linqToDb convert DateTimeKind for tableEntity.DT from **Local** to **UTC** and then throw an exception: `Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.`

But I need use 'timestamp without time zone'.

So - How to write C# DateTime by using LinqToDB in Postgres DB field 'timestamp without time zone'?

[image: before link command]
(the same rezult would be if kind were "Local")

[image: after linq2DB command]

Comment: Just to confirm, `LinqToDB` **is not** Entity Framework?

Comment: @Dai Yes, that is another ORM library - https://linq2db.github.io/

Comment: DateTime is stored as UTC which is a number.  When converting the number to/from a string the library method use the local timezone.  Be careful when convert between local and UTC which may cause expected results.  Most cases you only need to use convert is when you have a string in one timezone and convert to a string in another timezone.  Postgresql drivers passes string to the database so conversion is needed.  Other driver pass the datetime number to database and use UTC where conversion is not needed.

Comment: Have you tried simply: `tableEntity.DT = someDate`?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes,  I 've tried this way, It didn't help...

Comment: Please specify `linq2db` version.

Comment: If you still have issue, please create ticket in `linq2db` GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, this will surely solve your problem.
tableEntity.DT = DateTime.SpecifyKind(someDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

Comment: It didn't solve my problem,  result the same... I 've  added debbuger image in question.